# I have a value in my state i want to pass to another page

Tags: reactjs

I have a api call which takes in a varable from the state in my actions which goes to an axios get and it passes it there. I know this because if I console the variable in the axios get  its there  which goes to a route and to the controller but when I console loge the request in the controller  its empty. I am trying to do a find() to a specific email. If I hard code it then it works perfectly which means my variable probably isn't passing there and I don't know why. I have a post that works perfectly

my action

```
export const getUser = (currentUser) =>  {

return(dispatch, getState) => {

    API.getUserInfo({

        emailaddress:currentUser.emailaddress,
        password: currentUser.password


    })
    .then(res =>  {
                dispatch({type:"USER_PROFILE",userPro:res.data})
            })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));


}

}
```

reducer

```
const initState ={

        userProfile:[]




}

const userReducer = (state = initState,action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case "CREATE_USER" :
        console.log("created User", action.newProfile)
        return state;
        case "USER_PROFILE":
        console.log("User", action.userPro)
        return {
            userProfile: [...state.userProfile,action.userPro]
        }
        default:
        return state;

    }


}
```

root reducer

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
authR: authReducer,
userR:userReducer

})
```

mapstatetoprops

```
const mapStateToProps = (state)=>{
    console.log(state)
    return{
 userInfo:state.userR.userProfile


    }
}

export default connect(  mapStateToProps ) (Layout);
```

Comment: Multiple options, mobx, react context, redux

Comment: Use the context api https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: @jaydanasara. Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. I just wrote you a massive answer that at best should give you a high-level overview on the Redux library. This will help you achieve the performance that you're looking for. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, so you're now moving away from component state and into application state. This might end up being a long answer but in short I would suggest you read-up on the Redux and React-Redux documentation. https://redux.js.org/   https://react-redux.js.org/

`Redux` is all about persisting data in your application. Which is what you need if you want to take the data from one page and make it available for use in another page. It is essentially comprised of three parts:

**Actions**: Functions that are called to carry data from your components or APIs into a common place (reducers). The data is recognized as a "payload."

**Reducers**: Functions that are triggered by your actions. They use the "payload" to return a new app state (data).

**Store**: Just like the name suggests, it is an object that contains all your reducers; a collection of all your application states.

Now `react-redux` is simply middleware that let's your components communicate with your store.

There is some pretty standard mark-up to get this all to work. I'll show you examples with what I assume your code looks like.

So first let's define a reducer (a data maintainer for lack of better words) and lets store it in a file called **authReducer.js**

```
const authReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
   switch(action.type){
      CASE "SET_USER_CREDS":
         return {
             user: action.payload
         }
      default:
         return state
   }
}

export default authReducer
```

So digging into this code. We defined a function with two parameters, a state which we gave an initial value of {} and an action, which refers to the actions that get sent to this reducer. If there was an action with a type of "SET_USER_CREDS" then the reducer returns an object that will contain information on a user. As we can see, the only way it can get data is by consuming it from an action.

Now we need an action, a means to communicate with the reducer we just made. Let's create a file called **authActions.js**

```
export const recordUser = (userData) => {
   return {
     type: "SET_USER_CREDS":
     payload: userData
   }
}
```

Looks simple enough, we created a function that essentially is trying to meet the requirements of making our reducer to work. These action creators are actually used by our components, this is method in which we can get data from a component and keep it somewhere.

But wait, where do we keep this data? We talked about reducers, but where do they live? Well it's time to build our store.

**store.js**

```
import {createStore, combineReducers} from "redux"
import authReducer from "./authReducer"

const store = createStore(combineReducers({
   auth: authReducer
}))

export default store
```

Alright we got a store now. Quick facts about the syntax. We used a few methods fromt the redux library. We used createStore() and we passed in combineReducers(), where the latter accepts an object. In the object we define a key-value pair for each reducer we want to put in our store. The key is typically the name/type of data the reducer is managing.

Cool, we've set up a store, a reducer and an action-creator. But as is, there is no way for React to communicate with your store. Well this is where `react-redux` comes in. In whereever you defined your react-router-dom routes, we'll need to make some modifications.

Let's just say this is your router file, you'll need to add the following.

```
import {Provider} from "react-redux"
import store from "./store"

<Provider store={store}>
  //Routes
</Provider>
```

`<Provider>` is a component that accepts a redux-store as an argument. We can wrap our `<Routes/>` inside of it, thus providing the store to all our components.

Congrats, we're about 2 steps away from getting all this to work.

So now in your Header component, or wherever you're entering the user data you need to do a few things.

1) Bring in some dependencies.

```
import {connect} from "react-redux"
import {recordUser} from "./authActions"
```

2) Outside of your component. Define a function called mapDispatchToProps()

```
   const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
      return {
         recordUser: (userData) => {
            dispatch(recordUser(userData))
         }
      }
   }
```

In short, this is a function that will let us call your action-creators inside your component. The recordUser key is now an available prop inside your component.

3) Inside your component you need to define an event-handler to use our new prop. It will need to be triggered when the user is navigating to the other page.

```
handleRecordUser = () => {
   const userData = {
     email: this.state.email,
     password: this.state.password
   }
   this.props.recordUser(userData)
}
```

So its doing as we promised, taking data from our component state and passing it off to an action creator. Remember, you need to call this event-handler to execute this action at the same time as the re-route to the new page. If you're using a `<Link>` to reroute, just do something like:

4) Modify the export of this component to use `connect()`

```
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Header)
```

`connect()` gives our component access to methods like `dispatch()` which is a requirement to use your action-creators.

Last, but not least, consume your store.

In the component you routed to you need to do the following:

1) Bring in some dependencies.

```
import {connect} from "react-redux"
```

2) Outside your component, define a function called mapStateToProps()

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   return {
     auth: state.auth
   }
}
```

`mapStateToProps()` let's you tap into the store state and enables you to choose which reducer data you want to bring into your component. `state.auth` should look familiar, since in our **store.js** file we defined a key-value pair of {auth: authReducer}. We're simply calling that key.

So by defining a key of auth, I'm now saying that I will have a prop in my component called `this.props.auth` and it's value will be the reducer ouput.

3) Lastly, connect your component

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(YourComponent)
```

Now you can utilize the data from your previous Login component by consuming the saved data in your redux store by making use of `this.props.auth`.

Comment: @jaydanasara how did it go for you?

Comment: it seems to be working but it threw off my api call so I am trying to figure that our

Comment: What does the API call look like? Can you update your code above to show it?

Comment: I am having a reall problem posting code to this side it says use ctrl K but that's not working

Comment: Hmmm. Are you updating your original post? You wouldnt be able to post it in the comments here. You can really just select all of it, paste it onto the post text-box, highlight all of it and hit the {} button.

Comment: @jaydanasara are you getting any error from your api?

Comment: no just no response  or an empty object  unless I just use find() with out being specific then it works fine

Comment: hey I changed the axios call and the route to a .post and left the controller as a find({emailaddress:req.body.emailadress}) and it works but I am not sure why? also I am sure I am gonna need plenty other comparasions within the database before I am done and I am not sure this will work for the others. do you have any idea why this worked but the get wouldn't

Comment: @jaydanasara. The get request didn't work because get requests dont have access to a req.body. Only post requests have access to req.body :)

Comment: @jaydanasara. Awesome! well I'm glad you were able to integrate a full-stack app with react-redux. If you have anymore questions, please let me know. Also if you thought this answer was helpful to you, please mark it as the answer so others may find it for there reference.

Comment: so I have my app working thank you for your help but I have one question because I an not familiar with redux . after I run my api call and pull back my data and add it to the state and map the state to props I have my info but when I reload the state it goes back to the initial state

Comment: @jaydanasara. Hmm what do you mean by reloading the state? Do you mean like you refresh the page? Or you do an extra action and that ends up reverting your reducer? Feel free to update your original post with your reducer code.

Comment: when I refresh the page the state reverts back to initial state

Comment: Oh that's normal though :). If you refresh the page, you're essentially saying, "create a new instance of my application." Redux is good for persisting data on your current instance, not for all instances.

Comment: since I am taking info and triggering the call with a button on one page and sending the info to another page (page2) and using it on that page if I refresh that page how can I keep that info

Comment: You cannot keep that info if you refresh that page. If you want the 2nd page to have that info, you should be making the call to your API from there. Otherwise, it will always be dependent on you going to the 1st page.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) over here or you can use the localstorage, cookie, sessions any one of these browser storage to set the values and when your component gets rendered you can retrieve this data from browser and make your API call. Though this is not the best approach but if you don't know how to use redux then you can apply this.